# Edit one part of a nested list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

When I run following code in Python:

```
# create empty dummy dict
lst = [[0] for _ in range(2)]
dummy_dict = {'a': lst, 'b': lst}

# create dummy list
x_dummy = [1,2,3]

dummy_dict['a'][0] = x_dummy
print(dummy_dict)
```

I get this output for dummy_dict:

```
{'a': [[1, 2, 3], [0]], 'b': [[1, 2, 3], [0]]}
```

Why do I not get

```
{'a': [[1, 2, 3], [0]], 'b': [[0], [0]]}
```

and how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because even though you're only updating on one of the keys of the dictionary, they values of both keys are pointing to the same object:

```
id(dummy_dict['a'])
# 1752793882440

id(dummy_dict['b'])
# 1752793882440
```

hence all changes of this mutable object will be reflected across the other references to it.

Here's a dummy example, where you can see that modifying one of the inner lists of a list, does not create a new object, since lists as mentioned, are *mutable*

```
a = [[1,2,3], [0]]
id(a)
# 1752794665032

a[1] = [2]
id(a)
# 752794665032
```

---

**Solution**

Instead set the  dictionary values with copies of the list (taking a full slice copies the contents of a list)

```
dummy_dict = {k:lst[:] for k in ['a', 'b']}
dummy_dict['a'][0] = x_dummy
print(dummy_dict)
# {'a': [[1, 2, 3], [0]], 'b': [[0], [0]]}
```

Comment: don't forget the solution, i.e. copying the list

Comment: Yes true OP does ask `and how do I achieve this` @chris :) Will do